# Can a projective change of coordinates always be performed when the underlying field $k$ is arbitrary?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces

I am currently reading Kirwan's *Complex Algebraic Curves*, to understand the proof of Bézout's theorem given in the expository paper here : https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ggim/F11-214A.pdf .

In the paper, Bézout's theorem is proved for plane projective curves over a generally algebraic closed field $k$; however he references Kirwan's book in his proof, which only develops the theory over complex projective curves. This is fine for the most part, except when the author assumes that projective transformations can be used throughout to change coordinate systems so that certain points are not on the curves, and specific axes are tangent to specific point on the curves.

My question is, since in Kirwan these properties ultimately follow from the quotient topology defined on $\mathbb{P}_n (\mathbb{C})$ by $\mathbb{C}$, do they also transfer to when $k$ is an arbitrary algebraically closed field? I'm aware Bézout's theorem holds for any projective plane curves over an arbitrary field, but I am specifically looking to understand the methods used in Gim's paper.

Comment: Everything should be fine over any algebraically closed field. Can you make your question a little clearer about what results specifically you want to know? For instance, are the two things mentioned in the second paragraph all that you want to know? What's the precise statement of these that you actually need? Right now it's a little unclear to me what you actually want.

Comment: What do you mean by quotient topology? In this paper the author is considering $\mathbf{P}^n_k$ as a projective variety, hence endows it with the Zariski topology, not the quotient topology induced by $k^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Answering for completion:

Kirwan's use of projective change of coordinates throughout ultimately follows from the following theorem:

**Theorem**:
*Given four distinct points $p_0, p_1, p_2$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2}(k)$, no three of which are are collinear when viewed as points in $k^{2+1}$, there exists a projective transformation sending $p_0, p_1, p_2$ to $[1:0:0], [0:1:0],[0:0:1]$, and $q$ to $[1:1:1]\,$ respectively.*

A proof for which in the complex case can be found in his book cited above.